# Random number in an ordered set selection algorithm that doesn't repeat already generated selections in that set?

Tags: algorithm, random

Does anyone know of a random number selection algorithm that omits already generated numbers within a set without having to check against a set of numbers already generated? I was thinking each generated number gets added as a parameter to the algorithm as the numbers get generated, altering a random number generating equation.

I was doing something like the following to randomly input to a set of fields:

```
while(check == 0){
fieldNumber = mod(int(100/randomFractionalNumber); numberOfFields+1);
if(fieldIsEmpty(fieldNumber)){
setField(fieldNumber, foo);
check = 1;
}
}
```

Comment: You'd like the last random number to affect the next random number? Doesn't sound very random.

Comment: this is not a random number generator. If you're going to use it on a range 1..N then after N-1 flips you know what the next number is and after Y flips you definitely know which numbers will not appear.

This looks to me more like a shuffle of elements and getting them one by one in that shuffled order.

Comment: random number? Without same probability?

Comment: Meant random selection. I was randomly inputing into fields by modding a random fractional number divide into some number a little bigger than the number of field by the number of fields plus one. Then just checking if the selected field was empty or not. I thought this would get bad on huge number of fields. Was curious about doing something more tidy.

Comment: I want to shrink the set of outcomes each time around, but still randomly select from that shrunken set. Anyway most things called random shouldn't be random, like song selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might want to shuffle a list of numbers containing numbers from 1 to 1000; and take numbers sequentially from the shuffled list. Algorithms for shuffling a list of integers can be found easily, and most languages will have standard libraries implementing them: 
Fischer Yates Algorithm:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle 
C++ standard library function for shuffling an array:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle.

Comment: You could also use a stack which you shuffle as you go along - then by popping from the stack you are returning the item and removing it from the list in one step. You can then shuffle the remaining stack (Fisher Yates is a good call) and repeat.

Comment: You dont need to shuffle more than once. Shuffling once is as random as shuffling more than once.